# What is an optimal ratio of buy-in stack amt. to blind amt. for a 2hr+ home game?

Tags: rules, home-game

I am having a home NLH game with around 5-8 people that I want to have start at 10 and allow extra buy-ins until 12. How can I make the stacks not too deep and not too shallow to allow for the best amount of play in a 2hr+ game? My guess was to allow for 400 chip buy-ins with 1-2 chip blinds.

BONUS:
After 12 I want the blinds to raise, how is it best to do this?

Is it fair to allow extra buy-ins?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a re-buy format would be best for you.    For the first 2 hours, players can re-buy if they have chips less than or equal to the original stack.  This way the stacks will not start too deep, and people can only re-buy when they are low on chips.   It also stimulates action and builds your prize pool as well.  Once the two hours are up,  no more re-buys allowed.

At this time there is usually a break where players can purchase a one time "add-on" to their chips, which is almost always a little more than the original buy-in chip amount.   I have seen this be MUCH more though,  adding 3X-5X the re-buy chip amount at the add-on period.  It's up to you how many chips you want to allow.

You also will want to decide how often the blinds will go up and by how much.  This is a great way to get people up and out of your house if the game is running long.   :)  As the blinds go up, and players can no longer re-buy,  people will start quickly dropping from the tourny.

Sorry if you already know all this stuff, but I figured I should explain it in case anyone else needs the info too.  :)

> Example:
>
> Buy-in: $400 Player receives (for example) 1000 chips
>
> Re-Buy: $400 Players can re-buy if chip amount is 1000 or less (you
>   can decide if you want to let them do a "double re-buy" where they pay
>   twice the rebuy and get (in this example) 2000 chips.)
>
> Re-Buy Period: 2 hours After the re-buy period ends, no more re-buy's
>   will be allowed.
>
> Add-on: $400 One add-on of 1750 chips is available during the break
>   after the re-buy period ends.

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.  :)